# How is 2-hydroxy-ethoxy named?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

2-hydroxy-ethoxy is $\ce{HO-CH2-CH2-O}$.

I have a couple of confusions regarding this substituent.

Ethoxy is $\ce{-HO-CH2CH2}$ or $\ce{-OC2H5}$. So the $\ce{HO}$ in the above formula probably belongs to ethoxy.

Hydroxy (prefix for alcohol group) is $\ce{-OH}$. But if $\ce{HO}$ belongs to ethoxy, from where does hydroxy get its hydrogen?

Comment: 2-hydroxy-ethoxy is not the name of a *molecule* but the name of a radical (which usually means there is something else attached to the oxygen as illustrated in nandakumar's answer). Understanding this clears up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethoxy can actually **only** be $\ce{—O–CH2–CH3}$ and not that impossible $\ce{–HO–CH2CH2–}$ structure (which would require the oxygen to bear a positive charge and the last carbon a negative one).

The "2-hydroxy" derivative is then just replacing one hydrogen atom on $\ce{CH3}$ by a hydroxy ($\ce{OH}$) group, hence $\ce{HO–CH2CH2–O -}$.

Answer (score 2):

This group is called -(2-hydroxyethoxy)
e.g.:

[image]